# Why does over-clocking a CPU cause audio in Diablo 3 cinematics to go out of sync?

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I have recently purchased Diablo 3 and noticed that the sound in the cinematics of that game was out of sync and always a few seconds behind the visual and the subtitle.

I then read that overclocking of the CPU can cause that. As I usualy run my 3Ghz 960T at 4.2Ghz I decided to re-set it to the 3Ghz default.

The sound was now in sync again with the cinematic and subtitles in the game. All fixed.

- Why does overclocking the CPU affect the synchronicity between the cinematic and the sound?
- How come it does not effect cinematics in all games but only some (Diablo 3 being the first in my case)?

Comment: Speculation: Whatever video or audio codec they are using is reading the chip's native clock speed for some reason, and is calculating some durations based on that

Comment: @Nevir: I know it is not an issue if I stay at default clock speed but was just curious as to why clock speed would matter. Your comment would explain the exhibited behaviour alright. I wonder if Blizzard is using something custom written to stream the cinematics as I would have assumed a commercial streamer (or what ever you may call it) would not be causing synchronicity  issues with sound and picture due to over-clocking. Well, it is not a field I'm familiar with so I don't know any better anyway :)

Comment: Let's see if http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68597/what-video-audio-codec-does-blizzard-use-for-its-diablo-3-cinematics helps narrow it down

Comment: Is this a heat issue? My CPU is overclocked to 4.0ghz and has no problem with cutscenes.

Comment: @Resorath: Not sure if it is heat related but could well be. Blizzard recommends not overclocking the CPU to fix those sync issues so it seems to be a standard fix. My temps are just under 30 degrees. I have a massive dual-fan with copper rails on top of the CPU. Even when unlocking the additional 2 cores making it a 1060T 6 core CPU running at 4.2ghz it runs just under 35 degrees. I also don't have any issues with any other game's cinematics but again that does not mean it is not heat related off course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my I5-2500k OC'd to 4.5 Ghz. 
Your problem could have more to do with AMD specifically if it is indeed the processor that is the root of the issue. Is your machine a pre-built? 
I know that many pre-builts are not meant to be overclocked and the Power Supplies supplied are already at a ceiling.

I am assuming that this problem is only happening with Diablo 3. If not, then I would even go so far as to say there is an issue with your motherboard. Try to look up the model number and download all up to date drivers from the manufacturers website. Also, do the same for any discete graphics cards and your processor itself.

If the problems persist, please post back and I can try to suggest something further.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I upgraded a pre-build I bought in PC World a few years ago. I bought a new Gigabit mobo, 4gigs of matching dual channel RAM, new AMD 960T CPU, new dual-fan for CPU and new HD 6850 GPU. I had no issues when adding all the parts together and the sync issues only happens with this specific game. No other game shows that problem. It seems to be a well known issue as blizzard themselfes have posted on their forums that overclocking your CPU can cause this issue. Why it happens though is something blizzard has not said.

Comment: However, it could still be AMD related off course, but without blizzard giving up some more info its hard to figure out :) I also only upgraded my drivers to latest last night but haven't played D3 since then OCed. Will try when I get home and let you know :)

Comment: Definitely, your PC isn't stock anymore :-) Are there any error logs? It still has the potential to be a driver-related issue. Also, it may not be the audio that is out of sync, but the video. (unless it sounds like it is degraded in quality)

Comment: Could well be. The video and sound do not seem to stotter they just don't start at the same time. It's like the sounds either starts a second after the video or the video starts a second to fast before the sound. This is an issue with a lot of D3 players but you could be completly right and it is unique to OC'd AMD CPUs. :)

Comment: Have you noticed any other abnormally dark or blurry text? Anything that could attribute to a video card issue? Or possibly if you have a compatible video card laying around to test?

Comment: Haven't noticed anything else. Desktop is running fine and no crashes anywhere either. I double checked diablo 3 forums and the members which posted what fixed it for them was a mixed. Members with OCed CPUs (AMD or Intel) simply set the CPU speed to default and fixed it. Other with no OCed CPU had issue as their monitor was running at 120Mhz for example and setting that down to 60 fixed that. Some had issues with clashing audio drivers in which realtek was using theirs and AMD theirs at the same time, disabling the AMD one solved the issue from them.

Comment: After all that I think the comment from `Nevir` on the original post is most likely the most accurate or best guessed anyway :). Seems that with all those different speeds components are running in the codec Blizzard is using seems to be reading the base values differently than others do. In other games it seems less of an issue. Mind you, in the other games, the cinematics could be compiled or delivered differently as well. I'll be updating my audio drivers now and check again.

Comment: I hope this solves it for you! The cinematics are works of art and should be enjoyed!!! I've never known blizz to use a wonky codec that reads the clockspeed in such a way as to affect playback but hey, if it works, go for it! I wish I could test this out with my 955BE but my mobo blew recently.

Comment: Installed all latest GPU drivers and the Realtek drivers downloaded from the Gigabyt site from provider. Still no luck. The only fix working is to tune that GPU back down to 3Ghz default setting. Given the AMD overdrive app its easy to up it again to 4.2Ghz for COD-MoW3 in seconds :) I appreciate your effort and as yours is the only answer which actually made an effort to solve it I assign the bonus to you. I would have assigned it to `Nevir` but can't assign it to a comment. Thanks again. At least I got all drivers updated now :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, At least there is overdrive for you! Can you set a profile that will adjust itself at the launch of d3? That would be nice!

Answer (score -2):

This is not a professional answer however logically I think its one of these

1. You sound card can not handle the increased data traffic slowing the onboard sound processor.
2. You are need the max power draw and with a overclocked CPU its drawing power from the sound card.