# What video/audio codec does Blizzard use for its Diablo 3 cinematics?

Tags: diablo-iii

Prompted by [Why does over-clocking a CPU cause audio in Diablo 3 cinematics to go out of sync?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68242/why-does-over-clocking-a-cpu-cause-audio-in-diablo-3-cinematics-to-go-out-of-sync)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I extracted the first cinematic video to analyze it from MPQ archives (it is called `Cinematic_1_Intro.ogv`). I checked its properties using VLC and the video codec seems to be *Xiph.org's Theora Video*.

[image: other video codec details]

While audio codec is *Vorbis Audio (vorb)*.

[image: other audio codec details]

You can use [MPQ Editor](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html) if you want to try extract cinematic videos and play them outside Diablo 3 client.

Answer (score -2):

RALCWI (Robust Advanced Low Complexity Waveform Interpolation)

Comment: This information is wrong.